# How can I support anonymous users with my application?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, membership, anonymous

I need to implement a user authentication system that supports anonymous users, like how this site works. Can it be done with the default asp.net membership provider? if not, what are some of the things I need to do?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can be done. There's even a special event to migrate anonymous user details once the user logs in:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.profile.profilemodule.migrateanonymous.aspx